# Python object referencing

Tags: python, object

My goal is to create a list of tours. Each tour is a list as well.

The problem with this code is that at the end of the loop, the list `tours` is not a list of different, shuffled tours, but a list of the last tour that was added to the list. I imagine this has to do with Python object referencing but I do not know how to change this. I have tried `del tour` but to no avail.

```
def initialisePopulation(self, cities):
    tours = []

    for i in xrange(0, PopulationSize):
        tour = Tour(cities)
        shuffle(tour.tour)
        tours.append(tour)
        print str(tour.tour[0].id) + "," + str(tour.tour[1].id) + "," + str(tour.tour[2].id) + "," + str(tour.tour[3].id) + "," + str(tour.tour[4].id)
        del(tour)
    print "-"
    for j in xrange(0, PopulationSize):
        print str(tours[j].tour[0].id) + "," + str(tours[j].tour[1].id) + "," + str(tours[j].tour[2].id) + "," + str(tours[j].tour[3].id) + "," + str(tours[j].tour[4].id)
```

When I print each tour, everything is fine. When I print the contents of `tours`, each item is the same.
Here is the output:

```
2,3,1,5,4
2,4,3,1,5
2,3,4,1,5
4,3,1,5,2
3,4,1,5,2
-
3,4,1,5,2
3,4,1,5,2
3,4,1,5,2
3,4,1,5,2
3,4,1,5,2
```

Tour class:

```
class Tour(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self, cityList):
        self.tour = cityList
        self.size = len(cityList)
        self.fitness = self.getFitness(self.tour)

    def getFitness(self, tour):
        fitness = sum([self.euclideanDistance(tour[i], tour[i+1]) for i in xrange(0, self.size-1)])
        return fitness

    def euclideanDistance(self, p, q):
        distance = sqrt((p.x - q.x)**2 + (p.y - q.y)**2)
        return  distance
```

Comment: Can we see your `Tour` class? Because it looks like you are properly creating separate `Tour` instance here—but that all of the `Tour` instances are sharing a single list of cities.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that the problem is either (a) that `tour` is a class attribute instead of an instance attribute, so all instances have the same `tour`, or (b) that you're setting `self.tour = cities`, so each instance has a separate `tour` but they're all references to the same list.

Comment: As a side note, instead of writing `for j in xrange(0, PopulationSize):` only to use `tours[j]` inside the loop, just do `for tour in tours:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost certainly making one of two mistakes here—but it's in the code you haven't shown us, so I can't tell which one.

The first possibility is that you're storing `tour` as a class attribute instead of an instance attribute in Tours, so they're all sharing the same attribute:

```
class Tour(object):
    tour = something
```

The second possibility is that you're copying the list of cities into the `tour` instance attribute, so they all have different attributes, but all of them are references to the same list value:

```
class Tour(object):
    def __init__(self, cities):
        self.tour = cities
```

---

From your updated question, it's the second one.

This is ultimately identical to the [FAQ about multidimensional lists](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list), except that instead of directly having a list of lists, you have a list of objects that each wrap a list.

At any rate, you want each `Tour` to have a separate list, so you can mutate them separately with functions like `shuffle`, right? Then you will need to explicitly copy the list somewhere. For example:

```
class Tour(object):
    def __init__(self, cities):
        self.tour = cities[:]
```

---

However, I would probably write this differently. First, created a `shuffled` method that *doesn't* mutate in-place, but instead returns a new list:

```
def shuffled(iterable):
    result = list(iterable)
    shuffle(result)
    return result
```

Then you can replace your whole first loop with:

```
tours = [Tour(shuffled(cities)) for _ in xrange(PopulationSize)]
```

---

While we're at it, you can replace the second loop with:

```
for tour in tours:
    print ','.join(city.id for city in tour)
```

The [tutorial on `for` loops](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) explains the `for tour in tours` part. The second line uses a [comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [`join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to avoid repeating yourself five times.

Comment: @RupertCobbe-Warburton: OK, it's the second one.

Comment: Can't believe I confused copying with referencing the list! noob error. thanks a lot!